# Error C2065: a: необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте!

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <conio.h> // for getch()
#include <stdio.h> // for getchar(), putchar(), printf()

#define eof -1

int main()
{
    int c;
    printf("Make input \n");
    c = getchar;

    while(с != eof)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar;
    }

}
```

Не компилируется код в VS 2010. А вот код ошибки VS 2010:

```
1>  2.1_2010.cpp
1>2.1_2010.cpp(14): error C2440: =: невозможно преобразовать "int (__cdecl *)(void)" в "int"
1>          Не существует контекста, в котором такое преобразование возможно
1>2.1_2010.cpp(16): error C2065: a: необъявленный идентификатор
1>2.1_2010.cpp(16): fatal error C1903: не удается восстановить после предыдущих ошибок; остановка компиляции
```

В чём причина? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишете

```
c = getchar;
```

а нужно

```
c = getchar();
```

Кроме того, зачем определять `eof`? Есть же в `stdio.h` константа `EOF`. Грамотнее использовать ее.

Comment: Понял ошибку, спасибо. А то VS какую-то левую ошибку писала.  
Т.е. можно просто написать EOF без определения?

Comment: Конечно. Даже лучше, т.е. более переносимо

Comment: С циклом нет ошибки, это я сюда скопировал чуть не то, вы были правы, всё из за getchar без скобок.

Comment: Тут я сам прописал eof, так как задание в книжке требует поэкспериментировать с определением конца файла.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, наверное в задании подразумевалось один раз сравнение  с `EOF`, а другой раз анализ вызова `feof(stdin)`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы два раза пишете:

```
c = getchar;
```

Соответственно, компилятор думает, что вы значению переменной **c** пытаетесь присвоить адрес функции **int getchar(void)**.